# 'Not' before a noun subject in a question

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, nouns, interrogatives, negative-inversion

We know that if we don't use *contraction*, the structure of a **negative question** is as follows:

> Auxiliary verb + subject + not + verb ...?

e.g., (1) *'Does he not go to school everyday?'*

(2) *'Does the boy not go to school everyday?'*

But one of my friends tell me that the 2nd sentence is incorrect because in a negative-interrogative sentence, 'not' is used **after a pronoun subject, but before a noun subject:** *'Does not the boy go to school everyday?'*

I think in such case, 'not' is always used after the subject, no matter the subject is a noun or a pronoun.

Is the sentence *'Does not the boy go to school everyday?'* grammatically correct?

Comment: The form *does not the boy* sounds completely unnatural to me, even though *doesn't the boy* is unexceptionable. I think your (2) is how it would be said without a contraction.

Comment: By the way, there's a lot about this [in this question and its answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/577200/meaning-of-do-you-think-it-will-rain), although it's a hopelessly confusing muddle.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty: The form *does not the boy* sounds not unnatural to me, but formal and dated (I do read a lot of older literature however). It sounds like something a person in older literature would say.

Comment: @sharur How do you think *does not the boy* compares to *does the boy not*? To me, the second sounds stiff and dated; the first, just strange.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty "Does not a jew have eyes?" Shakespear; dated yes, but not "wrong". I also see that phrasing a lot in e.g. the Aubrey–Maturin series (Napoleonic was setting).

Comment: @sharur I found "hath not a Jew eyes"; that's a little different.

Comment: The important point to all these: You can do a lot to invert syntax without necessarily changing meaning (Yoda proves it), but it may or may not be common usage, and usages change.

Comment: @sharur (and Jack) and just a few lines later is "If you prick us, **do we not** bleed. Opposite usage. Both acceptable at the time and under poetic license, neither very colloquial now.

Comment: @AndyBonner But that apparently contrasting usage actually follows the rule proposed by the OP's friend, that pronouns come before the "not" and nouns after it. What has been missed in this discussion is that we all agree with the OP's friend on at least one point - we would be much less likely to say "do not we bleed?" than "do we not bleed?". The "do not we ...?" word order is possibly obsolete in modern English. By contrast, with the noun, both word orders are possible but (unlike the OP's friend) I would generally prefer to put the "not" after the nouns, too.

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is wrong to condemn "Does the boy not go to school every day."* In fact, if you wanted to add an intensifier, you'd have to use this form rather than the contraction: "Does the boy *really* not go to school every day?"

Your friend's suggestion is also valid, though very archaic in tone (for that matter, both examples with no contraction and no added modifiers are archaic in tone).

* (Well—technically all the examples are wrong because they use "everyday" to mean "every day," when really the one-word form should only be an adjective. But only someone hopelessly petty would be picky about that. And I'm sure that's not me...

Answer (score 0):

> - Does the boy not go to school every day?
> - Does not the boy go to school every day?

Both forms above would be easily understood by any fluent speaker. Both seem a bit formal and a bit old-fashioned to me, I can imagine either being used in  Dickens, or perhaps Robert Lewis Stevenson's *Kidnapped*  I agree that a modifier can make the first seem more natural

> Does the boy truly not go to school every day?

But I think that the suggested "rule" is another of the many attempts to compose rules for English that significantly understate the allowable variation in usage.

A somewhat more recent example:

> Could not the Germans have **sold** us these ships? (from Tuchman's *The Guns of August*, {Chapter: "Guben, An Enemy Then Flying"} reporting speech by a member of the Turkish cabinet in 1914, discussing how to "spin" an event.)

Since the original was probably in Turkish, this may be Tuchman's own translation. In any case it sounds natural to me.